# Process Comma Separated List from Key Value (expl3)

Tags: expl3, xparse, comma-separated-list, l3keys

I'm trying to `\SplitList` / `\ProcessList` a `clist` set in a wrapper command's argument as the value of a key.

Unfortunately, it seems that the original command (`\mycmd` below) doesn't recognize the input it receives as an actual list, and instead treats it as just one "item" (see contents above the horizontal rule in the output).

I'm sorry if I'm just being clumsy somehow, but any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }{
    \ProcessList{#1}{\myprocessline}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myprocessline}{m}{
    \noindent #1, and\par
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{mykeys}{
    mylist .clist_set:N = \l_mykeys_mylist_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrapper}{ O{} }{
    \keys_set:nn{mykeys}{#1}
    \mycmd{\l_mykeys_mylist_tl}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\wrapper[mylist={line one, line two, line three}]

\noindent\hrulefill

\mycmd{line one, line two, line three}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing a comma separated list, but something that *contains* a comma separated list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }{%
    \ProcessList{#1}{\myprocessline}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myprocessline}{m}{%
    \noindent #1, and\par
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{mykeys}
  {
    mylist .clist_set:N = \l_mykeys_mylist_clist
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrapper}{ O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn{mykeys}{#1}
    \exp_args:NV \mycmd \l_mykeys_mylist_clist
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\wrapper[mylist={line one, line two, line three}]

\noindent\hrulefill

\mycmd{line one, line two, line three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd use a different approach, because `\SplitList` is only meant for “simple” cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{ m }
  {
    \steve_mycmd_main:n { #1 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\wrapper}{ O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn{mykeys}{#1}
    \steve_mycmd_main:V \l_mykeys_mylist_clist
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \steve_mycmd_main:n
  {
    \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \steve_mycmd_processline:n
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \steve_mycmd_main:n { V }

\cs_new:Nn \steve_mycmd_processline:n
  {
    \noindent #1, ~ and\par
  }

\keys_define:nn{mykeys}
  {
    mylist .clist_set:N = \l_mykeys_mylist_clist
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\wrapper[mylist={line one, line two, line three}]

\noindent\hrulefill

\mycmd{line one, line two, line three}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the arguments of `\mycmd` in your `\wrapper` macro:

Use

```
\exp_args:Nx \mycmd {\l_mykeys_mylist_tl}
```